# stristr doesn't work for specific letters

Tags: php

has anyone ever needed to find text, which contains letters such as ā, ī ū š, ž and so on. My issue is, that stristr thinks, that ā and Ā isn't same letters. Also strtolower isn't working for these letters - it keeps Ā as Ā, not chaging it to ā. 
I really wouldn't like to write 11 str_replace for all 11 specific letters, but haven't found a better idea so far. And i haven't tested it yet, but i think, similar issues are going to be other language specific letters. 
What would you suggest?

Comment: Try setting encoding (charset) to be UTF-8 on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [mbstring](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mb_stristr](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stristr.php). It's the multibyte version of the same method.